# Rewrite URL but showed the original URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite `mysite/index.php?con=aaa&act=bbb&id=123` to `mysite/aaa/bbb/123'

This works perfectly in my site, but I have a directory called `manager` and I want to use the same rule in that directory. So I used this code to rewrite the URL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^manager/([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ manager/index.php?con=$1&act=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?con=$1&act=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

When I try to access

```
mysite/manager
```

my address bar is showing

```
mysite/manager/?con=manager&act=&id=
```

I don't know why the `manager` is treated as query.

Can anyone help me fix this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting redirected is because mod_dir will redirect any request for a directory that doesn't end with a trailing slash to the same URL with a trailing slash. You can turn this off by turning off `DirectorySlash`, but that makes your website vulnerable to information disclosure where anyone can see all the contents of your directories even if you have an index file.

You're better off either only accessing your directories with trailing slashes or turn off `DirectorySlash` and use mod_rewrite to handle it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Add that right below the `RewriteEngine On` line.